# How to obtain value for simple tags Django

Tags: django, django-cms

Hi everyone I create my first simple_tag passing a value, but I have problem to obtain the value

in my template I have this, the value that I have to pass is a string "footer1"

```
{% render_footer "footer1" %}﻿
```

now, my function is like this

```
def render_footer(footer_opc):
  home = Page.objects.get_home()
  return home.homeextension.footer_opc
```

in that case I supposed that  footer_opc = "footer1" so the return has to be home.homeextension.footer1, but don't work, y try  this too

```
def render_footer(footer_opc="footer1"):
  home = Page.objects.get_home()
  return home.homeextension.footer_opc
```

But I obtain the same result..
the code return `home.homeextension.footer_opc` , this no exist... but I don't know to obtain the value of footer_opc.

I try to return this to `return home.homeextension.+ footer_opc` but the same result.

Any idea! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is nothing to do with template tags.

To get an attribute by name from an object, use `getattr`.

```
return getattr(home.homeextension, footer_opc)
```